# PHP: how to extract ajax array response

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am getting ajax response in array format from php url. How to extract array response values in jQuery?
FYI:

PHP array is:

```
$response = array('msg' => 'Hello', 'html' => '<b>Good bye</b>');
```

I am getting $response array in my ajax response. i.e.

```
var promo = "promo=45fdf4684sfd";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseJsUrl + "/users/calc_discount",
    data: promo,
    success: function (msg) { // I am getting $response here as ajax response.
        //alert(msg);

        // Here I want to check whether response is in array format or not. if it is in array format, I want to extract msg here and want to use response array values.
    }
});
```

Let me know answer pls.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should echo that `$response` with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

You should probably set `dataType: 'json'` too inside the object literal you send to `$.ajax()`.

Then you can access it natively with JavaScript using the dot operator inside your success callback...

```
function(msg) {
    alert(msg.html);
}
```

BTW, this line...

```
$response = array(['msg'] => 'Hello', 'html' => '<b>Good bye</b>');
```

... [isn't valid PHP](http://codepad.org/Efbcf002). Remove the brackets from the first key.

Comment: Does your example really work? I have to parse the response first to got a result like this: **var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg); alert(obj.html);**

Comment: @Hexodus Depends on what jQuery function you're using to read it. If you tell it the response type is `json`, it will automatically parse it (which you *should* be doing).

Answer (score 1):

My favorite solution for this is to encode array with PHP's function json_encode() so jquery will be happy to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean a JSON response, like this:

```
{"msg":"Hello","html":"<b>Good bye<\/b>"}
```

This is actually a native JS object, so you can use it right away like this:

```
success: function(msg){
   alert(msg.msg);
   alert(msg.html);
}
```

You can also use the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to loop over all properties of the JSON object if you need to:

```
jQuery.each(msg, function(key, val) {
  alert(key + "=" + val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

and If you do not have control over the PHP output then you can use another method to get the result. 
Another solution is using http://phpjs.org/ library. Here you can find many functions available in JS as available in php. Usage is also same as that of PHP. So I feel if you get the json_encode/json_decode from there and use that then it can solve your problem easily.

Remember you can compile your needed functions only. In your case, it is json_encode and json_decode. No need to download whole library. Url to compile your library: http://phpjs.org/packages/configure

Comment: PHPJS's json_encode and _decode only works on JS objects, not on PHP equivalents.

Comment: Yes, Emil. You are right. I have not tested every function there but according to the way they are doing that json_encode/decode should work the same way as PHP counterpart is working. I have used few functions from there and that was working in correct way. Thanks for pointing the error.